# Understanding MySQL Dump files

Tags: mysql, output

I'm trying to understand "rename" a database by possibly modifying the dump file format

I've tried altering the DROP IF and CREATE and USE statements

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.21-20, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: music
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.7.21-20-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
```

At the moment it works, but I'm curious if line number 3

```
-- Host: localhost    Database: music
```

Has any affect on import -- so as it were:

```
mysql albums < music_db.sql
```

Does it end up in the DB Albums?